# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token bundle.js:formatted:1

Tags: javascript, html, css, babeljs, webpack-4

while using brotli compression algorithm for my react webapp i got this error in both browsers chrome and mozilla .All files are properly generted by brotli.It reduced my webapp size from 600kb to 139 kb ,but i dont why it is not working properly
my webpack

```js
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const outputDirectory = "dist";
const BrotliGzipPlugin = require('brotli-gzip-webpack-plugin')
const webpack = require("webpack");
module.exports = {
  entry: ["babel-polyfill", "./website/client/src/index.js"],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, outputDirectory),
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: ["file-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
        use: ["file-loader"]
      }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
  },
  externals: {
    // global app config object
    config: JSON.stringify({
      apiUrl: "http://localhost:4000"
    })
  },
  plugins: [
    new BrotliGzipPlugin({
      asset: '[path].br[query]',
            algorithm: 'brotli',
            test: /\.(js|css|html|svg)$/,
            threshold: 10240,
            minRatio: 0.8,
            quality: 11
  }),
  new BrotliGzipPlugin({
      asset: '[path].gz[query]',
      algorithm: 'gzip',
      test: /\.(js|css|html|svg)$/,
      threshold: 10240,
      minRatio: 0.8,
      quality:11
  }),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin({
      clearAfterEveryBuildPatterns: [outputDirectory]
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./public/index.html",
      favicon: "./public/favicon.ico"
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env.NODE_ENV": JSON.stringify("production")
    })
  ]
};
```

index.html

```html
 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>xyz</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"  integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/michalsnik/aos/2.1.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.0-2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <body>
        
        <div id="root"></div>
        <div id="preloader"></div>
        <a href="#" class="back-to-top"><i class="fas fa-arrow-up"></i></a>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" async integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" async integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.4.1/jquery.easing.js" async></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>     
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/michalsnik/aos/2.1.1/dist/aos.js" ></script>


</body>

</html>
```

express server configuration
I have set request Enconding headers according to different browsers

```js
app.get("/bundle.js", (req, res) => {
  if (req.header("Accept-Encoding").includes("br")) {
    console.log("calling brotli");
    res.set("Content-Encoding: br");
    res.set("Content-Type", "application/javascript");
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "..","..","dist","bundle.js.br"))
  } else if (req.header("Accept-Encoding").includes("gz")) {
    console.log("Calling gzip");
    res.set("Content-Encoding: gzip");
    res.set("Content-Type", "application/javascript");
    res.sendFile(path.join( __dirname, "..","..","dist", "bundle.js.gz"));
  } else {
    console.log("Calling Uncompressed");
    res.sendFile(path.join( __dirname, "..","..","dist", "bundle.js"));
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Changes my output webpack configuration to mulitiple types od bundle.js output

webpack.config.js

```js
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, outputDirectory),
    filename: "[name].bundle.js",
    chunkFilename: "[id].bundle.js"
  },
```

Now it works fine
take reference from https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/configuration#entry